# What does " -r " do in pip install -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package-managers, requirements.txt

I looked up how to install multiple packages from a requirements document using pip. The answers were mostly:

```
 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

What does the `-r` do though? I can't find an answer for this and it isn't listed when I run `pip help`.

Answer (score 57):

Instead of `pip --help`, look into `pip install --help`:

> -r, --requirement     Install from the given requirements
>   file. This option can be used multiple
>                                 times.

Also see these documentation paragraphs:

- [`pip install`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#pip-install)
- [Requirements Files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files).

Comment: This is the requirements file example from official website https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#example-requirements-file

Comment: So why do I have  `pip <command> [options] no such option: -r` ?

Comment: @Marine1 are you sure you are calling it as `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 14):

> `-r` will search for requirement file.

`pip install --help`

will help you !!

Answer (score 7):

### May, 2022 Update:

If you run this command below without **"-r"**:

```
pip install requirements.txt
```

You will get this error below:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requirements.txt (from versions: none)
> HINT: You are attempting to install a package literally named "requirements.txt" (which cannot exist). Consider using the '-r' flag to install the packages listed in requirements.txt
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for requirements.txt

Because **"pip"** tries to install **the package "requirements.txt"** instead of installing **the packages listed in "requirements.txt"**. Of cource, **the package "requirements.txt"** doesn't exist in [**PyPI**](https://pypi.org/) while for example, **the packages "django" and "pillow"** exist  in [**PyPI**](https://pypi.org/):

```
pip install django
```

```
pip install pillow
```

So, to install the packages listed in **"requirements.txt"**, you must need **"-r"**;

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You can check what **"-r"** means by running the command below:

```
pip install --help
```

> -r, --requirement     Install from the given requirements file. This option can be used multiple times.

Answer (score 5):

In your case `pip install -r requirements.txt` will install the libraries listed in your `requirements.txt` file.

Answer (score 4):

> pip install requirements.txt

Above statement looks for a python package named *requirements.txt*. No such package exists. Your intention is that *pip install* opens the txt and reads the packages from there. **The *-r* allows *pip install* to open *requirements.txt* and install the packages inside of it instead.**